# connection pool shutdown android

Tags: android, httpclient

I have a class for Httpclient. The same instance is used throughout the application. So if the client == null it should create one else it will return the existing instance. Everything works until i try to release the resource on exit by doing: client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();....after this i am not able to login again. It gives Sysem error saying : connection pool shutdown. Heres the class:

```
public class HttpClientFactory {
    private static DefaultHttpClient client;        
    public synchronized static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {
    if (client != null)
        return client;

    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry(); 
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));  
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();  
    SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);  
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, params);

    return client;
}
}
```

After this i simply run client.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); onBackPressed(),  can somebody please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok..i got the solution...I was not setting it back to null and connection shutdown is suppose to be done in the same global class...

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar issue, but set

```
client.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
client.getConnectionManager() = null
```

could not resolved the problem.

Finally, I found out that, I did close all connections in **onPostExecute**, which is incorrect, so after moving them into **doInBackground**, it works.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: why client.getConnectionManager() = null is needed?The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable